# action filter: redirect to logout and send a error msg

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, action-filter

IM new to MVC, this is w I need to do:

1. A person login to the app in 1 place (PC 1)
2. Goes to a different PC and login again (without login off from PC 1)
3. Someone try to use PC 1
4. PC 1 logoff
5. A error pages says "u have been logged of because..."

Until 4 im OK but I have the next code on my action filter:

```
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Items["errorMsg"] = Resources.Account.Res_String.SessionDuplica; //error msg and flag                       
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary(new
                                            {
                                                 controller = "Account",
                                                 action = "LogOff"                                                    
                                            }));
```

then on AccountController -> LogOff i have this:

```
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();


        if (HttpContext.Items["errorMsg"] == null)//normal logOff?
        {
            return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account");
        }
        else//induced logOff
        {
            ViewBag.error = HttpContext.Items["errorMsg"];
            return View();//LogOff view
        }
```

but if(HttpContext.Items["errorMsg"] == null= is always true

any know why? or another way to do this?

i just need to send a string from the action filter to the redirected method

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to logoff the same user in a different computer, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

> Gets a key/value collection that can be used to organize and share
>   data between an IHttpModule interface and an IHttpHandler interface
>   during an HTTP request.

Items It just only for single request, you need a session variable to solve this case.